# Keeping a counter after page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, storage

I need to keep a counter for a game that I am making. Each time they win a game, I want to add one to the counter. However, each time they win, the page is refreshed to start a new game. Is there a way to keep this counter updated even if the page is reloaded?

Comment: Store in a cookie or use DOM Storage or store to a DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cookies, here's a very simple example with jQuery cookie plugin:

Code: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Usage examples: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

**Set cookie:**

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 });
```

**Get cookie value:**

```
alert( $.cookie("example") );
```

Very clean and compact :)

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in a cookie or in localStorage if using compatible browser.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a cookie.  Mmmm... cookies.  Yummy.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie

Answer (score 0):

[w3school cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) gives a simple explanation for it. 
Shortly, it's a way to save your browser data on local machine.

```
// So, you may try
setCookie("win_count",value,exdays); // to set some data to "win_count"
// and after the page was reloaded to restore the win counter with the help of:
getCookie("win_count");
```

Answer (score 0):

***Use cookies***

jQuery:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 });
```

Pure JavaScript:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"))
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined
}

function setCookie(name, value, props) {
    props = props || {}
    var exp = props.expires

    if (typeof exp == "number" && exp) {
        var d = new Date()
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + exp * 1000)
        exp = props.expires = d
    }

    if (exp && exp.toUTCString) {
        props.expires = exp.toUTCString()
    }

    value = encodeURIComponent(value)

    var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value

    for (var propName in props) {
        updatedCookie += "; " + propName
        var propValue = props[propName]
        if (propValue !== true) {
            updatedCookie += "=" + propValue
        }
    }

    document.cookie = updatedCookie
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name, null, {
        expires: -1
    })
}
```